# jsTree with themeroller plugin: checkboxes won't show

Tags: jquery-ui, jstree

I'm using jstree pre 1.0 with the themeroller and checkbox plugin.
I'm using jquery ui 1.8.6 with the dark hive theme.

The tree is working fine, but the checkboxes are not shown.
Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the following 
1- are check boxes visible with other themes.
2- Have you tried firebug to see if there is any problem with loading the image.

Comment: Tried other themes without result. Looked at firebug, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

This may just be a temporary fix but it worked for me after I added the following css classes to my page:

```
.jstree ins {
background-image: url(http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/themes/default/d.png);
}

.jstree .jstree-unchecked > a > .jstree-checkbox {
background-position: -2px -19px;
}

.jstree .jstree-checked > a > .jstree-checkbox {
background-position: -38px -19px;
}

.jstree .jstree-undetermined > a > .jstree-checkbox {
background-position: -20px -19px;
}
```